# Find an asymptotic for $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{[nx ]} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}k \sin \frac{\pi j}{n} \sin \frac{\pi k j}{n} \cos^{[tn^2]} \frac{\pi j}{n}$

Tags: limits, summation

The problem is to find limit for $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{[nx]} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}k \sin \frac{\pi j}{n} \sin \frac{\pi k j}{n} \cos^{[tn^2]} \frac{\pi j}{n}$.

It is given that $x \in (0,1), t \in (0,1)$.

My ideas:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{[nx]} k \sin \frac{\pi k j}{n} \sim n\int_0^x t \sin \left(\pi t j \right)dt,$$
when $j/N << 0$, then
$$ \sin \frac{\pi j}{n} \cos^{[tn^2]} \frac{\pi j}{n} \sim \frac{\pi j}{n} \exp \left(-\frac{\pi^2 j^2 t}{2} \right),$$
so
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{[nx]} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}k \sin \frac{\pi j}{n} \sin \frac{\pi k j}{n} \cos^{[tn^2]} \frac{\pi j}{n} \rightarrow \pi \sum_{j=1}^\infty j \exp \left(-\frac{\pi^2 j^2 t}{2} \right) \int_0^x t \sin \left(\pi t j \right)dt,$$
but I don't know how to prove it mathematically.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Thank you for advice, improved question.